# How can I eliminate a duplicate result in XSLT 1.0?

Tags: xslt-1.0

I am using the Altova mapping tool and I cannot find an option on how to eliminate a duplicate value so I am trying to update the XSLT file directly and I cannot figure out how to do this.  Below is the XSLT file, the problem is in the Detail06 section.

```html
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   <xsl:template match="/">
    <AsyncBarcode>
      <xsl:variable name="var1_instance" select="." />
      <xsl:for-each select="$var1_instance/n:SyncReceiveDelivery">
        <xsl:variable name="var2_SyncReceiveDelivery" select="." />
        <Prefix>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:Sync/n:AccountingEntityID">
            <CompanyID>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
            </CompanyID>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:Sync/n:AccountingEntityID">
            <ExternalPartnerID>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
            </ExternalPartnerID>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <DocumentType>
            <xsl:value-of select="'AsyncBarcode'" />
          </DocumentType>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:ApplicationArea/n:BODID">
            <DocumentNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(string(.), ':1?'), 'Infor:')" />
            </DocumentNumber>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <TransactionDirection>
            <xsl:value-of select="'I'" />
          </TransactionDirection>
          <DateStamp>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(n:ApplicationArea/n:CreationDateTime), 'T')" />
          </DateStamp>
          <TimeStamp>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(string(n:ApplicationArea/n:CreationDateTime), 'T'), 'Z')" />
          </TimeStamp>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:ApplicationArea/n:BODID">
            <ControlNumber>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(substring-before(string(.), ':1?'), 'Infor:')" />
            </ControlNumber>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Prefix>
        <Header00>
          <TransactionDefinitionKey>
            <xsl:value-of select="'25'" />
          </TransactionDefinitionKey>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:Sync/n:AccountingEntityID">
            <CompanyID0>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
            </CompanyID0>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryHeader/n:DocumentReference/n:DocumentID">
            <xsl:variable name="var14_DocumentID" select="." />
            <xsl:if test="$var14_DocumentID/n:ID/@location">
              <BranchID>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(n:ID/@location), '-B')" />
              </BranchID>
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each>
          <UserID>
            <xsl:value-of select="'WMUser'" />
          </UserID>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryHeader/n:WarehouseLocation/n:ID">
            <WarehouseID>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(.), '-W')" />
            </WarehouseID>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Header00>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
          <Detail01>
            <xsl:for-each select="$var2_SyncReceiveDelivery/n:DataArea/n:Sync/n:AccountingEntityID">
              <Scanneddata1>
                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
              </Scanneddata1>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Detail01>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery">
          <xsl:variable name="var22_ReceiveDelivery" select="." />
          <xsl:for-each select="n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
            <Detail02>
              <xsl:for-each select="$var22_ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryHeader/n:DocumentReference/n:DocumentID">
                <xsl:variable name="var26_DocumentID" select="." />
                <xsl:if test="$var26_DocumentID/n:ID/@location">
                  <Scanneddata2>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(string(n:ID/@location), '-B')" />
                  </Scanneddata2>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </Detail02>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery">
          <xsl:variable name="var28_ReceiveDelivery" select="." />
          <xsl:for-each select="n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
            <Detail03>
              <xsl:for-each select="$var28_ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryHeader/n:DocumentReference/n:DocumentID">
                <Scanneddata3>
                  <xsl:value-of select="string(n:ID)" />
                </Scanneddata3>
              </xsl:for-each>
            </Detail03>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
          <Detail04>
            <xsl:for-each select="n:LineNumber">
              <Scanneddata4>
                <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
              </Scanneddata4>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Detail04>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
          <xsl:variable name="var38_ReceiveDeliveryItem" select="." />
          <Detail05>
            <xsl:variable name="var40_map_select_SerializedLot">
              <xsl:if test="string((n:SerializedLot/n:Lot/n:LotIDs/n:ID) = (n:SerializedLot/n:Lot/n:LotIDs/n:ID)) != 'false'">
                <xsl:value-of select="'1'" />
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="var48_">
              <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="string(boolean(string($var40_map_select_SerializedLot))) != 'false'">
                  <xsl:variable name="var45_map_select_SerializedLot">
                    <xsl:for-each select="n:SerializedLot/n:Lot/n:LotIDs/n:ID">
                      <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
                    </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:variable name="var41_map_select_SerializedLot">
                    <xsl:if test="string((string($var45_map_select_SerializedLot)) = (string($var45_map_select_SerializedLot))) != 'false'">
                      <xsl:value-of select="'1'" />
                    </xsl:if>
                  </xsl:variable>
                  <xsl:if test="string(boolean(string($var41_map_select_SerializedLot))) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:variable name="var42_map_select_SerializedLot">
                      <xsl:for-each select="n:SerializedLot/n:Lot/n:LotIDs/n:ID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
                      </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:value-of select="string($var42_map_select_SerializedLot)" />
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                  <xsl:value-of select="' '" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <Scanneddata5>
              <xsl:copy-of select="$var48_" />
            </Scanneddata5>
          </Detail05>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
          <Detail06>
            <xsl:for-each select="n:HoldCodes/n:Code">
              <Scanneddata6>
                <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="string((' ' != string(.))) != 'false'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Hold'" />
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="'Inventory'" />
                  </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
              </Scanneddata6>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Detail06>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <Detail07>
          <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryHeader/n:ReceivedDateTime">
            <Scanneddata7>
              <xsl:value-of select="string(.)" />
            </Scanneddata7>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </Detail07>
        <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem">
          <Detail11>
            <xsl:for-each select="n:ReceivedQuantity">
              <Scanneddata11>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(string(.))" />
              </Scanneddata11>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Detail11>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </AsyncBarcode>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Below is the input I am receiving:

```html
<SyncReceiveDelivery xmlns="http://schema.infor.com/InforOAGIS/2" releaseID="9.2" versionID="2.8.0">
  <ApplicationArea>
    <Sender>
      <LogicalID>lid://</LogicalID>
      <ComponentID>Warehouse Management</ComponentID>
      <ReferenceID accountingEntity="01" location="RS01-W">0000058141</ReferenceID>
    </Sender>
    <CreationDateTime>2015-03-31T20:08:16Z</CreationDateTime>
    <BODID>infor-nid:infor:01:RS01-W:0000002445:62883?ReceiveDelivery&amp;verb=Sync</BODID>
  </ApplicationArea>
  <DataArea>
    <Sync>
      <TenantID>infor</TenantID>
      <AccountingEntityID>01</AccountingEntityID>
      <LocationID accountingEntity="01">RS01-W</LocationID>
      <ActionCriteria>
        <ActionExpression actionCode="Add" />
      </ActionCriteria>
    </Sync>
    <ReceiveDelivery>
      <ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
        <DocumentID>
          <ID accountingEntity="01" location="RS01-W" variationID="62883">0000002445</ID>
        </DocumentID>
        <LastModificationDateTime>2015-03-31T20:08:12Z</LastModificationDateTime>
        <DocumentDateTime>2015-03-31T20:08:12Z</DocumentDateTime>
        <DocumentReference type="CustomerReturn">
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="01" location="1323-B">930131</ID>
          </DocumentID>
        </DocumentReference>
        <Status>
          <Code listID="ReceiveDeliveryStatus">Received</Code>
        </Status>
        <WarehouseLocation>
          <ID accountingEntity="01">RS01-W</ID>
          <Name languageID="en-US">Power Packaging</Name>
          <Address>
            <AddressLine sequence="1">401 N. Main</AddressLine>
            <CityName>Rosendale</CityName>
            <CountrySubDivisionCode>WI</CountrySubDivisionCode>
            <PostalCode listID="PostalCode">54974</PostalCode>
          </Address>
        </WarehouseLocation>
        <ActualDeliveryDateTime>2015-03-31T17:31:46Z</ActualDeliveryDateTime>
        <GrossWeightMeasure unitCode="LB">8120.4147</GrossWeightMeasure>
        <TotalVolumeMeasure unitCode="CF">0</TotalVolumeMeasure>
        <ShipFromParty>
          <Location>
            <ID>30155</ID>
            <Name languageID="en-US">RS-IFP-USFS HOUSTON</Name>
            <Address>
              <AddressLine sequence="1">USFS HOUSTON</AddressLine>
              <AddressLine sequence="2">111 ALIANT DRIVE</AddressLine>
              <CityName>HOUSTON</CityName>
              <CountrySubDivisionCode>TX</CountrySubDivisionCode>
              <CountryCode>USA</CountryCode>
              <PostalCode listID="PostalCode">77032</PostalCode>
            </Address>
          </Location>
        </ShipFromParty>
        <ReceivedDateTime>2015-03-31T20:08:12Z</ReceivedDateTime>
        <DeliverToParty>
          <Location>
            <ID accountingEntity="01">RS01-W</ID>
            <Name languageID="en-US">Power Packaging</Name>
            <Address>
              <AddressLine sequence="1">401 N. Main</AddressLine>
              <CityName>Rosendale</CityName>
              <CountrySubDivisionCode>WI</CountrySubDivisionCode>
              <PostalCode listID="PostalCode">54974</PostalCode>
            </Address>
          </Location>
        </DeliverToParty>
        <ASNReference>
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="01" location="RS01-W">0000002445</ID>
          </DocumentID>
        </ASNReference>
      </ReceiveDeliveryHeader>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <ItemID>
          <ID accountingEntity="01">200135-100250</ID>
        </ItemID>
        <ServiceIndicator>false</ServiceIndicator>
        <Description languageID="en-US">Orchard Splash 12/25 fl oz Orange Gold 100</Description>
        <Note languageID="en-US">1</Note>
        <DocumentReference type="CustomerReturn">
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="01" location="1323-B">930131</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        </DocumentReference>
        <PackingSlipQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipQuantity>
        <PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedQuantity>
        <ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReturnedQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedQuantity>
        <ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <SerializedLot>
          <ItemQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemQuantity>
          <ItemBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemBaseUOMQuantity>
          <Lot>
            <LotIDs>
              <ID>RS1412107</ID>
            </LotIDs>
            <Quantity unitCode="CS">90.0</Quantity>
            <BaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</BaseUOMQuantity>
          </Lot>
        </SerializedLot>
        <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">HOLD</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">QCREQ</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <CountSequence>1</CountSequence>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <ItemID>
          <ID accountingEntity="01">200135-100252</ID>
        </ItemID>
        <ServiceIndicator>false</ServiceIndicator>
        <Description languageID="en-US">Orchard Hills 12/25 fl oz Orange 100</Description>
        <Note languageID="en-US">2</Note>
        <DocumentReference type="CustomerReturn">
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="01" location="1323-B">930131</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        </DocumentReference>
        <PackingSlipQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipQuantity>
        <PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedQuantity>
        <ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReturnedQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedQuantity>
        <ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <SerializedLot>
          <ItemQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemQuantity>
          <ItemBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemBaseUOMQuantity>
          <Lot>
            <LotIDs>
              <ID>RS141112</ID>
            </LotIDs>
            <Quantity unitCode="CS">90.0</Quantity>
            <BaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</BaseUOMQuantity>
          </Lot>
        </SerializedLot>
        <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">HOLD</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">QCREQ</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <CountSequence>1</CountSequence>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
      <ReceiveDeliveryItem>
        <ItemID>
          <ID accountingEntity="01">200135-100252</ID>
        </ItemID>
        <ServiceIndicator>false</ServiceIndicator>
        <Description languageID="en-US">Orchard Hills 12/25 fl oz Orange 100</Description>
        <Note languageID="en-US">3</Note>
        <DocumentReference type="CustomerReturn">
          <DocumentID>
            <ID accountingEntity="01" location="1323-B">930131</ID>
          </DocumentID>
          <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        </DocumentReference>
        <PackingSlipQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipQuantity>
        <PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</PackingSlipBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReceivedQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedQuantity>
        <ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ReceivedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <ReturnedQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedQuantity>
        <ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">0.0</ReturnedBaseUOMQuantity>
        <SerializedLot>
          <ItemQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemQuantity>
          <ItemBaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</ItemBaseUOMQuantity>
          <Lot>
            <LotIDs>
              <ID>RS1412030</ID>
            </LotIDs>
            <Quantity unitCode="CS">90.0</Quantity>
            <BaseUOMQuantity unitCode="CS">90.0</BaseUOMQuantity>
          </Lot>
        </SerializedLot>
        <LineNumber>3</LineNumber>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">HOLD</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <HoldCodes>
          <Code listID="Hold Reason Codes">QCREQ</Code>
        </HoldCodes>
        <CountSequence>1</CountSequence>
      </ReceiveDeliveryItem>
    </ReceiveDelivery>
  </DataArea>
</SyncReceiveDelivery>
```

Finally, this is what I am expecting however I am getting duplicates values in Scannedata6 for the Detail06 section:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE AsyncBarcode SYSTEM "C:/InboundBODS/AsyncBarcode_Inbound.dtd">
<AsyncBarcode>
  <Prefix>
    <CompanyID>01</CompanyID>
    <ExternalPartnerID>01</ExternalPartnerID>
    <DocumentType>AsyncBarcode</DocumentType>
    <DocumentNumber/>
    <TransactionDirection>I</TransactionDirection>
    <DateStamp>2015-03-31</DateStamp>
    <TimeStamp>20:08:16</TimeStamp>
    <ControlNumber/>
  </Prefix>
  <Header00>
    <TransactionDefinitionKey>25</TransactionDefinitionKey>
    <CompanyID0>01</CompanyID0>
    <BranchID>1323</BranchID>
    <UserID>WMUser</UserID>
    <WarehouseID>RS01</WarehouseID>
  </Header00>
  <Detail01>
    <Scanneddata1>01</Scanneddata1>
  </Detail01>
  <Detail01>
    <Scanneddata1>01</Scanneddata1>
  </Detail01>
  <Detail01>
    <Scanneddata1>01</Scanneddata1>
  </Detail01>
  <Detail02>
    <Scanneddata2>1323</Scanneddata2>
  </Detail02>
  <Detail02>
    <Scanneddata2>1323</Scanneddata2>
  </Detail02>
  <Detail02>
    <Scanneddata2>1323</Scanneddata2>
  </Detail02>
  <Detail03>
    <Scanneddata3>930131</Scanneddata3>
  </Detail03>
  <Detail03>
    <Scanneddata3>930131</Scanneddata3>
  </Detail03>
  <Detail03>
    <Scanneddata3>930131</Scanneddata3>
  </Detail03>
  <Detail04>
    <Scanneddata4>1</Scanneddata4>
  </Detail04>
  <Detail04>
    <Scanneddata4>2</Scanneddata4>
  </Detail04>
  <Detail04>
    <Scanneddata4>3</Scanneddata4>
  </Detail04>
  <Detail05>
    <Scanneddata5>RS1412107</Scanneddata5>
  </Detail05>
  <Detail05>
    <Scanneddata5>RS141112</Scanneddata5>
  </Detail05>
  <Detail05>
    <Scanneddata5>RS1412030</Scanneddata5>
  </Detail05>
  <Detail06>
    <Scanneddata6>Hold</Scanneddata6>
  </Detail06>
  <Detail06>
    <Scanneddata6>Hold</Scanneddata6>
  </Detail06>
  <Detail06>
    <Scanneddata6>Hold</Scanneddata6>
  </Detail06>
  <Detail07>
    <Scanneddata7>2015-03-31T20:08:12Z</Scanneddata7>
  </Detail07>
  <Detail11>
    <Scanneddata11>90</Scanneddata11>
  </Detail11>
  <Detail11>
    <Scanneddata11>90</Scanneddata11>
  </Detail11>
  <Detail11>
    <Scanneddata11>90</Scanneddata11>
  </Detail11>
</AsyncBarcode>
```

Comment: Your XSLT does not match your input. Please provide a [minimal but complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can run to reproduce your problem - and include the expected result, too.

Comment: Thank you.  I've updated my post with this information.

Comment: It's neither minimal nor complete.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not a programmer so I just added the entire XSLT, Input file and expected output.  I know it's not minimal but it is complete.

Comment: Correction, i removed some of the information from the very beginning of the XSLT file.

Comment: If you're writing XSLT, or mucking around in someone else's XSLT in order to make it behave slightly differently, you're enough of a programmer to cut it down to the smallest program you can make that still exhibits the problem.  (Unfortunately, sometimes in the process you see the difficulty, understand the solution, and the question goes away.  But that's a risk you just have to take.)

Comment: I was able to resolve the problem with a very simple change.  I think it was dumb luck but I kept at it.  Here is the change I made:

Comment: <xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem/n:HoldCodes[1]">
<Detail06>
<xsl:for-each select="n:Code[1]">
<Scanneddata6>
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="string(('' != string(.))) != 'false'">
<xsl:value-of select="'Hold'"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
<xsl:value-of select="'Inventory'"/>
</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
</Scanneddata6>
</xsl:for-each>
</Detail06>
</xsl:for-each>

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure out what I needed to change. Change shown below:

```html
<xsl:for-each select="n:DataArea/n:ReceiveDelivery/n:ReceiveDeliveryItem/n:HoldCodes[1]">
  <Detail06>
    <xsl:for-each select="n:Code[1]">
      <Scanneddata6>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string(('' != string(.))) != 'false'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'Hold'" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Inventory'" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </Scanneddata6>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Detail06>
</xsl:for-each>
```